# MySql passing paramater gives different result

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core web site and I am loading some products from database with this command:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ROBAID, KATBR, NAZIV,
                            SLIKA FROM ROBA WHERE PODGRUPAID IN (@PG)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", "PODGRUPAID");

    // Other reading code
}
```

Problem is this way I am getting only first 2 products as result (inside MySqlDataReader inside inspector) but when I change command string to `SELECT ROBAID, KATBR, NAZIV, SLIKA FROM ROBA WHERE PODGRUPAID IN (PODGRUPAID)` without adding parameter through command, I get all results...

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of PODGRUPAID?  Is PODGRUPAID something like 'A, B, C'?  If so, the command will work more like `SELECT ROBAID, KATBR, NAZIV, SLIKA FROM ROBA WHERE PODGRUPAID = 'A, B, C'` (as a whole string).  You can try [Using comma separated value parameter strings in SQL IN clauses](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're passing `PODGRUPAID` as a string in this parameter value definition:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", "PODGRUPAID");
```

This causing only values which has certain value of `PODGRUPAID` will be selected, and I found that you can't simply add parameters to `IN` clause like that. If you want to include multiple values, you could use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in place of `IN` clause:

```csharp
string podGrupAIDs = "value1,value2,...";

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT ROBAID, KATBR, NAZIV,
                            SLIKA FROM ROBA WHERE FIND_IN_SET(PODGRUPAID, @PG)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", podGrupAIDs);

    // Other reading code
}
```

If the values are coming from an array or `List<T>` (`T` = any value type), you can join them with `string.Join()` before using `FIND_IN_SET`:

```csharp
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "value1", "value2", ... };

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT ROBAID, KATBR, NAZIV,
                            SLIKA FROM ROBA WHERE FIND_IN_SET(PODGRUPAID, @PG)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", string.Join(",", values));

    // Other reading code
}
```